# Powershell - try/catch in foreach

Tags: powershell, try-catch

This code writes errors in Catch block and stops executing

```
$Result=""   
$Results=@() 


    $Customers = Get-PartnerCustomer
Try{
    $Customers.ForEach({
                $CustId = $_.CustomerId
                $CustName =$_.Name
                $CustomerUser = Get-PartnerCustomerUser -CustomerId $CustId | Where-Object {
                $_.DisplayName -like 'name'
                } | ForEach-Object {
                $_.DisplayName
                #$_.UserPrincipalName
              }
              $Result=@{'Customer Name'=$CustName;'User Name'=$CustomerUser}
              $Results+= New-Object PSObject -Property $Result
                          
            })
    }
Catch{
      Write-Warning "Caught an exception:"
      Write-Warning "Exception Type: $($_.Exception.GetType().FullName)"
      Write-Warning "Exception Message: $($_.Exception.Message) - Tenant:$CustName"
}
```

When adding `$ErrorActionPreference="Continue"` at the top script continues after error but writes generic error message

```
Get-PartnerCustomerUser : Access denied.
At line:8 char:33
+ ...   $CustomerUser = Get-PartnerCustomerUser -CustomerId $CustId | Where ...
+                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Get-PartnerCustomerUser], PartnerException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Store.PartnerCenter.PowerShell.Commands.GetPartnerCustomerUser
```

With `$ErrorActionPreference="SilentlyContinue"` it doesn't output any errors.

Is it possible to show my custom error message and not exiting from loop on first error ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved, had to add `Try/Catch` inside the `ForEach`

```
$ErrorActionPreference="Stop"

    $Customers = Get-PartnerCustomer

    $Customers.ForEach({
    Try{
                $CustId = $_.CustomerId
                $CustName =$_.Name
                $CustomerUser = Get-PartnerCustomerUser -CustomerId $CustId | Where-Object {
                $_.DisplayName -like 'Name'
                } | ForEach-Object {
                $_.DisplayName
                #$_.UserPrincipalName
              }
              $Result=@{'Customer Name'=$CustName;'User Name'=$CustomerUser}
              $Results+= New-Object PSObject -Property $Result
                                        
            }
            
            Catch{
      Write-Warning "Caught an exception:"
      Write-Warning "Exception Type: $($_.Exception.GetType().FullName)"
      Write-Warning "Exception Message: $($_.Exception.Message) - Tenant:$CustName"
     }
   }
  )
```

Comment: You can also reference `$Error` which holds all errors. Something like `$Error | Select Exception` should return the actual error type. Based off your first question

Comment: Thanks, code i posted gives me fine error output